# Why std::vector requires operator =

Tags: c++, stl

I have a question about a class that we can store in vector.
What is the requirement that can be stored in a vector?
It seems that such class has to have assignment operator. But I am not sure if that's all or not.

Let me give you an example. class A has const int member. If I don't write operator =, it doesn't compile. But in this example, this operator does nothing. This program displays 10 and 20 correctly. It looks that operator = is required but not used in reality.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
 public:
  A(int a) : a_(a) {}
  A& operator =(const A& a2) { return *this;} // Without this, compile fails.
  void print() const {
    std::cerr << a_ << std::endl;
  }
 private:
  const int a_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::vector<A> v;
  v.push_back(A(10));
  v.push_back(A(20));
  for (const A& a : v) a.print();
}
```

Comment: You need a copy constructor or a move constructor.

Comment: It compiles on VS2012 and Gcc 4.8, which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Rapptz I've actually found that you need both copy constructor and copy-assignment, OR move constructor and move-assignment. VS2012 uses the copy/move constructors internally. GCC seems to want the copy/move assignments instead.

Comment: @Mysticial Works [fine for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f4dcd50cc3967df552395c0f4f5f963e-93e6c6235a92d0c233f44beab03470ad)

Comment: @Rapptz Hmm... I've an object in a `std::vector` that had move-constructor, but no move-assignment. It compiled in VS2012, but linker-errored in GCC (specifically for missing the move-assignment). Though I doubt it matters, I *think* I was using GCC 4.6.

Comment: @Rapptz the member in your example isn't `const`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore We were discussing something else sort of irrelevant to the question. Though if you make it `const` nothing changes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I compiled with clang 3.1. That looks implementation dependent.

Comment: @zorio Not really. I have no idea what your code's issue is because it works fine with [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a02e46046f42549b3d78660b5426f6f1-93e6c6235a92d0c233f44beab03470ad). I think you're missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might surprise you:

```
v.push_back(A(20));
v.push_back(A(10));
std::sort(begin(v), end(v));
```

There are aspects of vector itself that require assignability, though I don't know, offhand, which (and I can't tell by compiling your code, since my compiler doesn't complain when I remove `operator=()`). According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C%2B%2B%29#cite_note-C.2B.2B03_23.1.2F4-2) (which references the relevant portion of the '03 standard), elements must be `CopyConstructible` and `Assignable`.

**EDIT:** Coming back to this a day later, it seems forehead-slappingly obvious when `std::vector` requires `Assignable` — any time it has to move elements around. Add a call to `v.insert()` or `v.erase()`, for example, and the compile will fail.

Comment: Thank you.I understand it doesn't sort. It totally makes sense. Why push_back fails?

Comment: @zorio: `push_back()` doesn't fail. I was simply showing that the contents aren't sorted before calling `sort()`.

Comment: I used clang. That behavior looks implementation dependent.
And the requirements are CopyConstructible and Assignable. Thinking about your code snippet, these requirements make sense.

Thank you.

Comment: It compiles without defined *operator=* on GCC and clang.

Answer (score 3):

> If I don't write operator =, it doesn't compile.

That surprised me, so I had a look into the standard and I found:

### **Your example has an implicitly deleted copy constructor but should still compile if a conforming C++11 standard library is at hand.**

The only expression that puts constraints on the type used by the `vector` in your example is `push_back`.

The `push_back()` method of a sequence container type `X<T,A>` with allocator `A` and `value_type` `T`, requires `T` to be:

- *CopyInsertable* if an lvalue or const rvalue reference is passed
- *MoveInsertable* if a non-const rvalue is passed

Which means it requires a valid copy constructor or (as in this case) a valid move constructor which will be implicitly present from your code. Therefore the compilation should not fail in any compiler with a valid C++11 standard library.

### Operations that require the type, contained in a `vector` to be assignable:

#### Ancillary conditions

```
typdef std::vector<T> X;
X a,b;
X&& rv;
X::value_type t;
X::value_type&& u;
X::size_type n;
X::const_iterator p,q; // p = valid for a, q = valid and dereferencable
initializer_list<T> il;
[i,j) -> valid iterator-range
```

#### Pessimistic`*` list of operations

The operations, which require `T` to be assignable, if X is a `vector`, are:

```
Statement              Requirement on T

a = b;                 CopyInsertable, CopyAssignable
a = rv;                MoveInsertable, MoveAssignable
a = il;                CopyAssignable
a.emplace(p, args);    MoveInsertable, MoveAssignable
a.insert(p, t);        CopyAssignable
a.insert(p, u);        MoveAssignable
a.insert(p, n, t);     CopyInsertable, CopyAssignable
a.insert(p, i, j);     EmplaceConstructible[from *i], MoveInsertable, MoveAssignable
a.insert(p, il);       -> a.insert(p, il.begin(), il.end());
a.erase(q);            MoveAssignable
a.erase(q1,q2)         MoveAssignable
a.assign(i,j);         Assignable from *i
a.assign(il);          -> a.assign(il.begin(), il.end());
a.assign(n,t)          CopyAssignable
```

`*` = Pessimistic means that there may exist certain conditions for several requirements to actually come into effect. If you use one of the expressions listed above, your type `T` will likely be required to be assignable.

Answer (score 2):

push_back on vector will make vector grow in memory, that means 
old objects needs to be copied to new object via assignment operator= 
hence you need assignment operator=.

Comment: That is actually done by the copy constructor, maybe when using the reserve functionality push_back might do that (i'm not sure about that case), but operator= is used when you construct a vector with the specified number of elements (use the vector constructor with a size_t parameter) and use [] to get a reference and assign it a value, also some algorithms (like the already mentioned sort) might use operator=

Answer (score -1):

The availability of copy constructor and assignment operator are guaranteed by the compiler if you don't create any of your own. (the correctness of default implementation, is a different story though).   In your example, you *almost* don't have to overload A::opeartor=().

The problem here is not a "missing" operator=(), but that the default one cannot be used, because you have declared a const data member

```
const int a_;
```

The default compiler generated operator=() cannot assign value to a const member.  So you have to overload your self:

```
A & A::opeartor=(const A & in)
{
    *const_cast<int*>(&a_) = in.a_; // !!!you are expected to do this.
}
```

So, your version of A::operator=() that does nothing, although making the code compile, does't change the a_ value of the left hand operand,

Comment: 1. The `operator=()` definition is indeed missing since it's "deleted". 2. Implicit `operator=` is always "correct". It's not meant to do what you expect but that's probably a mistake in your expectation not in the implicit assignment operator. 3. You are **NOT** expected to do such `const_cast` stuff(!!!). It should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Not sure why you downvote this answer. I did say that "the correctness of default implementation is a different story".  I am not doing such const_cast stuff.  This is to deal with the original issue that the user declares a const member while wanting to do assignment operation on the object.

Comment: He actually doesn't want to do an assignment and he didn't ask "how to assign const members". He just wondered why storing his class in a vector brings up the requirement to define an assignment operator. Furthermore is the const_cast assignment not required to take place for the compiler to accept the assignment operator. OP wrote one and it fits. I suspect the fact that it "does't change the a_ value of the left hand operand" is inteded here.

Comment: The `const_cast` is invalid code, pure and simple: it is undefined behaviour to cast away `const` on an object that was originally declared `const`, and your program can blow up in an infinite number of surprising ways if you do so. You are not "_expected to do this_": you are **not allowed** to do it, and woe betide if you do.